# replicating different data model

Tags: oracle, replication, esb, timesten

I have an application A which has around 100+ tables and uses Oracle DB. There is another application B which uses this data stored in its timesten DB with less number of tables.

Given 2 different types of databases with different data models ,achieving  DB-DB replication is not easy.Not all data from application  A required to be replicated to application B.

We are proposing application B to develop a web service which will be exposed to application A for replicating data. Basically application A will transform the data in the format required by application B and then use B's web service to replicate the data.

Not sure if it is the best way to replicate when the source system and target system have different data Models. Is there any standard practice for this kind of replication ?

Comment: Surely the *"standard practice"* is [to build the TT tables with the provided Timesten utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21631/overview.htm#TTCIN293) and refresh them with [the built-in functioality](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21634/operations.htm#TTCAC266)?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for high sophisticate programming, which demands a lot of tests and years and years of development to find a good ETL process for this.

Oracle have a solution for this
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html